# laravel livewire how to call function value

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-7, laravel-livewire

I am trying to call the function value in suppliers_master_id but it's showing error

**my code**

```
 public $form = [
'supplier'          => '',
'email'              => '',
'phone'              => '',
'address'            => '',
'city'               => '',
'state'              => '',
'pincode'            => '',
'GSTIN'              => '',
'suppliers_master_id' => $this->generateRegistrationId()
```

];

**function code**

```
    function generateRegistrationId() {
    $id = 'SIIT_' . mt_rand(1000000000, 9999999999);

      if ($this->registrationIdExists($id)) {
        return $this->generateRegistrationId();
    }
    return $id;
     }
    function registrationIdExists($id) {
    return Supplier::where('suppliers_master_id', $id)->exists();
    }
```

Comment: @Clément Baconnier can you help this question

Comment: What's the error even

Comment: what is the error?